# UITableView with JSON Error

Tags: json, uitableview, afnetworking

I have an app and it's using JSON and an UITableView.
When I try to build/run my app it says: `No known class method for selector 'JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:success:failure`

This is my code:
http://hastebin.com/axaxumosam.m
The error occurs on line 48.

Hope that you can help me.

Greetings Rik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are trying to use older delegate on the newer version of the API:

[**AFNetworking 2.0 Migration Guide**](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-2.0-Migration-Guide)

> One of the most significant changes in AFNetworking 2.0 is its new
>   architecture for content negotiation and serialization. Previously,
>   response validation and serialization was delegated to
>   AFHTTPRequestOperation and its subclasses, with content-specific logic
>   scattered throughout implementations for
>   setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:failure: and other properties. In 2.0,
>   all of this logic is encapsulated in a serializer object that conforms
>   to **AFURLResponseSerialization**.